# jquery - .hide() .show() ruins CSS styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I have a div containing a set of textboxes and buttons which is showing by default. I also have a set of tournament brackets made using jquery, which is set to `display: none`.

```
$('#buttontest').click(function() {
    $('div.bracket').show();
    $('div.teamList').hide();
});
```

When I use this code, it works so that the swap around in terms of what is showing, but when it shows the tournament brackets, it ruins the css styling behind it, the teams on the tournament tree do not match up. I have linked 2 screenshots at the bottom to highlight this.

Here is what the tournament tree should look like

[image]

But when I hide the brackets, and show them after the button is clicked, it ends up like this

[image]

Here is my code for the HTML side of things it is in JADE template HTML language, but it is easy enough to see what is going on :)

```
div.teamList
    form.pull-left(method="post", id="loginForm")
        input.input-small(id="team1", type="text", name="Team 1", placeholder="Team 1")
        input.input-small(id="team2", type="text", name="Team 2", placeholder="Team 2")
        br
        input.input-small(id="team3", type="text", name="Team 3", placeholder="Team 3")
        input.input-small(id="team4", type="text", name="Team 4", placeholder="Team 4")
        br
        input.input-small(id="team5", type="text", name="Team 5", placeholder="Team 5")
        input.input-small(id="team6", type="text", name="Team 6", placeholder="Team 6")
        br
        input.input-small(id="team7", type="text", name="Team 7", placeholder="Team 7")
        input.input-small(id="team8", type="text", name="Team 8", placeholder="Team 8")
        br
        button.btn.btn-primary.btn-mini(type="submit", value="Submit") Submit
        button#buttontest.btn.btn-primary.btn-mini(type="button") Submit
div.container
    div.bracket
```

https://raw.github.com/teijo/jquery-bracket/master/jquery.bracket.js

https://raw.github.com/teijo/jquery-bracket/master/jquery.bracket.css

And the singleElim - http://pastebin.com/z6KvRqGU

Comment: Use `addClass('hidden')` instead.

Comment: Not sure how to do this, the form hides perfectly fine, but no matter where I show the bracket, the alignment is always wrong

Comment: I'm on my phone which makes typing code difficult. Show and hide add display: inline or block depending on the element.

Comment: Can you provide the generated html of the brackets?

Comment: @Michael_B I am using http://www.aropupu.fi/bracket/ this to generate brackets, not sure why this is changing the layout of my brackets if I am honest, I thought it would work fine as it works fine every time except when it is hidden then shown...

Comment: @zzzzBov This did not work also.

Comment: Have you tried re-initializing the bracket after you 'show'?

Comment: @Michael_B inside the bracket div is #singleElim which is the javascript initializing the brackets is using to know to initialize, so i dont know how you would "re-initialize" the bracket

Comment: Could you update your question with your singleElim and any bracket jquery you are using?

Comment: @Michael_B I have added jquery.bracket files and my singleElim to initialize the brackets, thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21492/discussion-between-michael-b-and-germainelol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to leave the `.bracket` div visible until you've initialized the bracket.  So remove `display:none` from your `custom.css` stylesheet and then do this n your `singleElim8.js` file.

```
$(function() {
    $('#singleElim8').bracket({
        init: singleElim8Data
    })
    $('.bracket').hide();
});
```

In your 8teams jade use your original js:

```
$('#buttontest').click(function() {
    $('div.bracket').show();
    $('div.teamList').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Include `clearfix`

Include clearfix CSS and add it this way:

```
div.container.clearfix
```

Or simple, give this `div` a CSS of `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: `.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}` This is included in my .css file yes, but no matter which div I add this to I still get the aligning error, could you expand on which div to add a css of `overflow: hidden` to please and how to do that?

Comment: The `div` on which the gradient background is there. BTW, the full clearfix am specifying is this: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: This didn't work either, I am using jquery-bracket from here http://www.aropupu.fi/bracket/

Comment: Oh, will need to play around it... Can you show a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K4W6u/1/ This is the main page, and the javascript/css file provided by jquery-bracket, i also have twitter bootstrap css being used, but it's a problem with the brackets i guess. just dont know which part should be changed...

Comment: @germainelol, your jsFiddle is broken. Have it work to show the problem.

Comment: @arttronics This is very hard to do with several js files and I am using jade template not html :/

Comment: @germainelol, then unfortunately the jsFiddle is of no use if the problem can't be replicated there.